# How to display multi dimensional Javascript array in tabular format in the console?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, console.log

I have searched everywhere, I didn't notice this weird interaction at first but now I am, I am learning JavaScript in codeacademy and i'm stuck in Arrays and Objects in JavaScript, when I do this:

```
var newArray = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];
console.log(newArray)
```

It logs the code as in the same line instead of having 3 rows and 3 columns as it is asked by the exercise, however it lets me pass it, I have searched on their forums and there's users asking for the same thing unanswered, I've tried the possible fixes like resetting the browser and even changing browser.

Comment: you expect console to write it to three lines? I have a feeling the exercise is asking for something else.

Comment: Yes, at least that's what the exercise example told me it would do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `console.table()`.

```
var newArray = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];
console.table(newArray);
```

Here is a good list of all the console commands available for future reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console

This is what it will look like in Firefox (will look similar in other browsers).

[image]

Comment: sadly this is true, it doesn't work on the console, i guess they're forcing me to do it manually so that later on they can teach me something else. (Which is a design flaw as it made me search for an answer for like 1 hour...), i'll still rate yours as most useful for the table command.

Answer (score 0):

Try console.table(newArray) instead, if you're using Chrome.

Otherwise console.dir(newArray) might make things a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

That's normal, and might even be different from browser to browser, as there's no specification as to how `console.log` output should be formatted.

You can write:

```
var newArray = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];
console.log(newArray[0]);
console.log(newArray[1]);
console.log(newArray[2]);
console.log(newArray[3]);
```

This will output the individual "subarrays" on separate lines.

Comment: Oh, i get it, it accepts my answer because the "multidimensional" array is correct but the console log isn't i should be doing that instead, thanks i didn't understand why it was letting me pass without doing what was intended in by the exercise.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a custom logger:

```
var newArray = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]];

var logArrayOfArrays = function(array){
   var length = array.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < length ; i++){
       console.log(array[i]);
  }
}

logArrayOfArrays(newArray);
```